# Can't set properly WordPress add_filter function

Tags: filters

I'm trying to add icon to the button using `add_filter()` function:

```
function sh_woocompare_button_icon($text)
{
 return  '<i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="tm_woocompare_product_actions_tip"><span class="text">' . $text  . '</span></span>';
}
add_filter( 'tm_woocompare_button', 'sh_woocompare_button_icon');
```

And I want to apply changes to the function:

```
function tm_woocompare_add_button( $args ) {
    $id      = get_the_ID();
    $id      = tm_wc_compare_wishlist()->get_original_product_id( $id );
    $classes = array( 'button', 'tm-woocompare-button', 'btn', 'btn-default' );
    $nonce   = wp_create_nonce( 'tm_woocompare' . $id );

    if ( in_array( $id, tm_woocompare_get_list() ) ) {
        $text      = get_option( 'tm_woocompare_remove_text', __( 'Remove from Compare', 'tm-wc-compare-wishlist' ) );
        $classes[] = ' in_compare';
    } else {
        $text = get_option( 'tm_woocompare_compare_text', __( 'Add to Compare', 'tm-wc-compare-wishlist' ) );
    }
    $text      = '<span class="tm_woocompare_product_actions_tip"><span class="text">' . esc_html( $text ) . '</span></span>';
    $preloader = apply_filters( 'tm_wc_compare_wishlist_button_preloader', '' );

    if( $single = ( is_array( $args ) && isset( $args['single'] ) && $args['single'] ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'tm-woocompare-button-single';
    }
    $html = sprintf( '<button type="button" class="%s" data-id="%s" data-nonce="%s">%s</button>', implode( ' ', $classes ), $id, $nonce, $text . $preloader );

    echo apply_filters( 'tm_woocompare_button', $html, $classes, $id, $nonce, $text, $preloader );

    if( in_array( $id, tm_woocompare_get_list() ) && $single ) {
        echo tm_woocompare_page_button();
    }
}
```

As the result `$text` variable outputs whole button code as simple text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution!

```
function woocompare_button_icon( $html, $classes, $id, $nonce, $text, $preloader )
{
    return sprintf( '<button type="button" class="%s" data-id="%s" data-nonce="%s"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> %s</button>', implode( ' ', $classes ), $id, $nonce, $text . $preloader );
}

add_filter( 'tm_woocompare_button', 'woocompare_button_icon', 10, 6);
```